# Mininet openflow tutorial

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow, wireshark-dissector

I am new to mininet and trying to follow the tutorial on mininet/openflow https://github.com/mininet/openflow-tutorial/wiki/Learn-Development-Tools

I have a problem with the Wireshark capture, it's only capturing TCP packets on the lo interface, no OpenFlow packets at all.

any idea what might be wrong?

Cheers,
ami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you use openflow on port `6634` but as you can see [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/OpenFlow) in wireshark documentation it expects to see OpenFlow packets on port `6633` or `6653`.

I prefer to use third party controller but if you want to use mininet default controller, you can set its port with:

```
sudo controller ptcp:6653
```

Comment: It was a port problem, as you guessed. when starting mininet it tries to add the controller on ports 6633 or 6653. I had to specify the port when calling the controller by: "controller ptcp:6653"
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: you can use other controllers like onos or floodlight and I thinks these are much better than mininet default controller. If you want I can complete my answer so have all things in one place.

Answer (score 0):

[mininet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29PwZ.png)

when starting Mininet, it sets the controller in my case to port 6653.
Calling the openflow controller later on, I had to specify the port too:`sudo controller ptcp:6653`